# Azure cloud service fails to run in development

Tags: windows, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a azure cloud service project running on my Windows 8 machine in Visual Studio 2012. It has a website and a few ddl projects. The solution is checked into Team Foundation Server.

When I run the project in Windows 7, its starts the emulator and works great.

When I run the project in Windows 8, the emulator starts, but the website never starts. Visual studio 2012 has a message as the bottom that says the following :
The program '[4188] WaIISHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The operation was canceled.

How do I debug this and get it to work?

EDIT 14/04/2014
I am having the same problem with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Can you check event logs if there's an entry there regarding this error?

Comment: Here are the entries to the event viewer: (dont know how to get a new line when entering a comment!

Comment: Guest Agent finished initializing.

Comment: Executing system program "C:\<Project>\csx\Debug\roles\<Project Name>\plugins\Diagnostics\DiagnosticsAgent.exe"  with task type 2. Working Directory is C:\<Project>\csx\Debug\roles\<Project Name>\plugins\Diagnostics. Module Name is Diagnostics.

Comment: Executing system program "C:\<Project>\csx\Debug\roles\<Project Name>\plugins\Diagnostics\DiagnosticsAgent.exe" /blockStartup with task type 0. Working Directory is C:\<Project>\csx\Debug\roles\<Project Name>\plugins\Diagnostics. Module Name is Diagnostics.

Comment: System program "C:\<Project>\csx\Debug\roles\<Project Name>\plugins\Diagnostics\DiagnosticsAgent.exe" /blockStartup exited with zero exit code 0. Working Directory is C:\<Project>\csx\Debug\roles\<Project Name>\plugins\Diagnostics. Module Name is Diagnostics.

Comment: Deploying IIS sites started. Process ID: 7988, Process Name: IISConfigurator Deploying sites from package started.

Comment: Deploying IIS sites finished. Process ID: 7988, Process Name: IISConfigurator Deploying sites finished.

Comment: Okay, I have got it to work following this links suggestions - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/01/04/handling-problem-diagnostics-monitor-is-not-sending-diagnostics-logs-to-azure-storage-after-upgrading-windows-azure-sdk-from-1-2-to-1-3.aspx. Basically, I commented out the <Sites> tags in the ServiceDefinition.

Comment: Commenting out the <Sites> tag  works temporarily but is not idle. Has anyone find a better solution?